# Can't read XML data

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, gzip, webclient, httprequest

I want to read xml file from remote server but somehow the server doesn't response to my request. Therefore, Gzip throws "The magic number in GZip header is not correct" exception. Any idea?

```
 private static string GetFile()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://www.iddaa.com.tr/XML/IDDAAMACPROGRAMI/index.htm?iddaadrawid=12.09.2012&iddaadrawide=13.09.2012&foraccess=KSsec654");

        string xmlFile;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
        req.UserAgent =
            "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
        req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");


        using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),
                                               CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(zip);
            xmlFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return xmlFile;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use gzip. The `HttpWebRequest` will automatically do this for you if the server sends gzip header to the response.

But you could even further simplify your code using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
private static string GetFile()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate";
        var xmlFile = client.DownloadString("http://www.iddaa.com.tr/XML/IDDAAMACPROGRAMI/index.htm?iddaadrawid=12.09.2012&iddaadrawide=13.09.2012&foraccess=KSsec654");
        return xmlFile;
    }
}
```

or the new [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) class that was introduced in .NET 4.5:

```
private async Task<string> GetFile()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.iddaa.com.tr") })
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("MOZILLA", "5.0"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("(WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64)"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("APPLEWEBKIT", "537.1"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("(KHTML, LIKE GECKO)"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("CHROME", "21.0.1180.75"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("SAFARI", "537.1"));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xhtml+xml"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml", 0.9));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*", 0.8));

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
        var result = await client.GetAsync("/XML/IDDAAMACPROGRAMI/index.htm?iddaadrawid=12.09.2012&iddaadrawide=13.09.2012&foraccess=KSsec654");
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: @user712847, if this answer helped you solve the problem you were having please consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you very much.. I was looking to get back the XML error response that could occur on my REST HTTP GET request... and this one line ' return await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();' from your above code sample, saved my day!